# How to call function that takes callbacks as parameters in Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to implement [ReachFive](https://developer.reach5.co/guides/installation/android/) in my android app and I have to call the initialize method.

This is how they call it in the documentation:

```
    // Initialize the ReachFive client
    client.initialize({ providers ->
        // On success, do something with the retrieved list of providers registered for this ReachFive client
        // ...
    }, {
        // On failure, log the error message returned by the ReachFive client
        Log.d("Reach5_MainActivity", "ReachFive init ${it.message}")
    })
```

But this code sample is in Kotlin and I have no idea how to call the `initialize` method in java.

Edit: This is the `initialize` function find inside the SDK code:

```
fun initialize(
    success: Success<List<Provider>> = {},
    failure: Failure<ReachFiveError> = {}
): ReachFive {
    reachFiveApi
        .clientConfig(mapOf("client_id" to sdkConfig.clientId))
        .enqueue(
            ReachFiveApiCallback<ClientConfigResponse>(
                success = { clientConfig ->
                    scope = clientConfig.scope.split(" ").toSet()
                    providersConfigs(success, failure)
                },
                failure = failure
            )
        )

    return this
}
```

Comment: Each lambda is functional interface. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (put the implementation/logic of your functions instead of dots)

```
client.initialize((providers) -> {...}, (error) -> {...});
```

Note that your first method should return an instance of `Success<List<Provider>>` and your second lambda should return `Failure<ReachFiveError>`.

Comment: That's it ! Thank you :)

Comment: @R3J3CT3D you are welcome! Please note, that the method above simply passes objects of **Functional Interface** to initialize method. In my answer I declared them anonymously, whereas they can also be declared explicitly. You should read about it more